# direct upload to s3 fails with Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

When I use `local` as storage service, a blob will be created like:

`ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "9GRt2oNEvae3MV6gNxzLBfzY"], ["filename", "22.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 38908], ["checksum", "HWkFPEByP/zWdy1nDW6FHg=="], ["created_at", "2018-07-09 07:53:34.790031"]]`

notice the `checksum` in it is `HWkFPEByP/zWdy1nDW6FHg==`, while I switched the storage service from local to amazon, the file upload to s3 failed, and the error says:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>BadDigest</Code><Message>The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.</Message><ExpectedDigest>1d0c39a9937ce0bec2952fe2be1c4f51</ExpectedDigest><CalculatedDigest>iSb43Wodm0WQp/hAZpKKOg==</CalculatedDigest><RequestId>9018707DCFFCA829</RequestId><HostId>Nop+tXGRYKJlhIy7LU+d4nYtba9i1n3BYnNM+Il60WlH0ZhR53SyHCS2Nox+KVgie9XTIlTOGTg=</HostId></Error>`

notice the calculated digest is `iSb43Wodm0WQp/hAZpKKOg==`, I am not sure which is wrong, Rails or Amazon, please find the picture I am trying to upload here [image]

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you get the same error in a different browser?

Comment: @GeorgeClaghorn I was uploading from within React Native using XmlHttpRequest, the code looks pretty much like http://blog.rudikovac.com/react-native-upload-any-file-to-s3-with-a-presigned-url/

Comment: How are you retrieving a direct upload URL? If you’re using the [built-in direct uploads controller](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2cc514a74a293d175904c08fd74b8a037d8959e2/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/direct_uploads_controller.rb), are you sending the headers it returns to S3?

Comment: @GeorgeClaghorn Yes, I am sending a POST request to server side to create a new blob, and sending the headers it returns to S3

Comment: @GeorgeClaghorn this is how the `direct_uploads_controller.rb` looks like

https://gist.github.com/leomayleomay/a522e8012e8c6fc7125768746ee1bf07

Comment: How are you computing the checksum you send when requesting a direct upload URL?

Comment: @GeorgeClaghorn I passed the MD5 from client side and do further calculation on server side here https://gist.github.com/leomayleomay/a522e8012e8c6fc7125768746ee1bf07#file-direct_uploads_controller-rb-L36

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174680/discussion-between-leomayleomay-and-george-claghorn).